# Return an error to Ajax from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling

I have a simple Javascript funcion:

```
function checkParams()
{
  $.ajax(
  {
    url: 'login.php',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    data: 
    {
      user: $("#user").val(),
      pass: $("#pass").val()
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      $("#mydiv").load("loader.php");
    },
    error: function()
    {
      $("#mydiv").load("index.php");
    }
  }); 
}
```

And A simple PHP function which checks for the right **user** & **pass** string and I should return an error condition if something fails..

I found examples where it's suggested to do something like:

```
function foo()
{
  /* code ... */

  /*error condition */
  echo "error";
}
```

But honestly, it's not working..

How can I tell to ajax, from PHP, that I want ro return an 'error condition' ?

Answer (score 3):

The [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) error handler only fires when the HTTP status result indicates an error; that is, the page returns a 4xx or 5xx status code.

You can do one of the two following options:

1) Set the status code with `header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request')` (or any other relevant HTTP status code) before you echo "error".

2) Rather than using an error status, have both your success and failure conditions emit an array, converted to JSON with`json_encode()`, that is then decoded in your javascript and processed into a success or failure as appropriate in your success function.

Comment: Precisely what I do. I always try to return a JSON response with a property indicating the "status".

Answer (score 0):

In this bit of code change to RETURN SOMETHING

```
success: function(data)
{
  return true;
},
error: function()
{
  return false;
}
```

basically 
$result = your ajax return;

```
if ($result)
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
    }
else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Yourserver');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 'whatever you want to call it')));
    }
```

Comment: Just asking, is it appropriate to return an error 500 for a failed login attempt?

Comment: for failed login just return FALSE and do your PHP code based on the result. 500 is a server side problem. not a failed login. it means client couldn't reach the server.

Comment: I never heard of any Content-Type called "index.php" before.

Comment: I asked because the OP expected to process the failed login in the error event, and seen your answer I was wondering if it was an acceptable (uncommon for sure) practice. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson ... A typo ... thanks for mentioning it